# ReactJS: run function to spawn elements from different pages without interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I made this thing which scrapes a website and posts it differently with react. I need some help with it. The divs are supposed to float up on their own after spawning and they should get new posts from the website afterwards. However, right now, it just floats up the first 10 posts available on the website. Right now I have a button which functions based off of onClick but I want the posts to just come out on their own and not repeat.

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>

    {/*I have a component elsewhere*/}
    {this.state.posts.map((post) => {
      return (<Post post={post} key={post.id}></Post>);
    })}

    <div className="load-more">
      <a className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick=this.loadMore.bind(this)>Load more</a>
    </div>
   </div>
 );
}
```

This is my loadMore function. I don't want it to be clicked based though. I just want it to run. It is in the same component as the one above.

```
loadMore(){
  let posts = this.state.posts;
  let lastPost = posts[posts.length - 1];

  $.ajax({
    url: this.paginationURL(),
    data: { page: lastPost.id },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (response) => {
      this.setState({
        posts: this.state.posts.concat(response.posts)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone! If you need more information feel free to put it under the comments section. If you have even just a slight idea, feel free to just leave a link for me to read up on so I can get pointed in the right direction. All kinds of help appreciated!

Comment: so what's the problem? Just run it if you want ;)

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't phrase my question properly. It keeps looping on the first few elements the website loads.

Comment: Still not clear what is going on (as I cannot reproduce your testcase). Did json request ok? Did it returned data you need? How do you really caal it?

Comment: Yes the request sent properly. I call it with this: this.loadMore.bind(this)

I'm not sure why it's not working. The repository is too big to share :/

Comment: I like to guess riddles, but I am weak in this, sorry

Comment: We're good! Thanks for the help guys. I'll share my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, you have to put your scraping mechanism in a poll/interval to update the DOM as you scrape new data.

Something like:

```
// Lets say this is where you need to put the scraped posts
const wherePostsShouldBe = <div id="posts"></div>;

// Auto-run the scraping every 3 seconds.
setInterval(scrapePosts(), 3000)

// Do the scraping
function scrapePosts() {

  $.ajax({

    url: 'http://where-to-scrape-things.com',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: (response) => {
      // So we scraped some data. Now update the element with these.
      // This actually re-renders everything again including old and potentially new data.
      // But its ok to stay primitive for now. Including simply displaying the entire data we got without serializing.
      ReactDOM.render(
        response.posts,
        document.getElementById('posts')
      );
    }

  });

}
```

Haven't tested this. But this should give you some idea.